# What is the fastest way to show a regular grid with OpenGL using vertex buffer?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, optimization, 3d

So I have a matrix of points of a digital elevation model, lets say 1024x1024 grid with a cell spacing of 1 unit.

I wan't to display this DEM with OpenGL the fastest possible way in c++ using vertex buffer.
Since my data set is fragmented in tiles, I will have to do a lot of loading as I move the camera so this will need to be very fast.

What is the fastest way to show a grid like this? Do I need to do some sort of triangulation or is there a faster way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried whether or not a naive implementation is fast enough? A mesh with 1024x1024 vertices doesn't sound like it's even worth optimizing. Don't optimize until you have something to actually profile.

Comment: @IInspectable I have hundreds of those tiles and they will be generated on the fly. That's why it needs to be fast. Otherwise the user experience will suffer.

Answer (score 4):

Correct in OpenGL you have to triangulate first. If you just want a simple solution, you can use the scheme pictured below.

You turn each data point into a vertex. The data point's indices become x and y coordinates; the height value becomes the z coordinate.

Now you have to create a vertex index list. The first triangle has indices [0, 1, 1024], the second [1024, 1, 1025], and so on. You draw your arrays as `GL_TRIANGLES`.

[image: Triangulation Scheme]

There are [more efficient ways to triangulate height fields](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/user/garland/www/scape/scape.pdf) but I would not go there unless you really have to.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to initialize a 1024x1024 vertex buffer with evenly spaced x-z coordinates. The height can be sampled in the vertex shader by a 1024x1024 pixel height texture per patch. The vertex buffer can be re-rendered per visible patch, providing different height textures and different x-z coordinate offsets.

Comment: Or better yet, calculate X-Z based on the vertex index, requiring no buffer at all.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the x-z coordinates. Do you mean a 1024x1024 buffer where the value stored in the buffer are the z values of every x-y positions and the grid represents a x-y coordinates system?

Comment: In OpenGL: x and z are the two horizontal axes. y is the height axis.